# BGE, logic bricks, setting up a timer (that reverses at some point)

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

with the delay actuator I set up a "timer" that adds +1 every 60ticks to a "timer" property.

Now I want it to count backwards after it reaches 4 and, when it becomes 0, again goes up to 4 and so on and so on.

Has anybody an idea how to achieve this with logic bricks? Or is python neede?
Thanks for every suggestions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logic bricks are best explained with an image :

[image: logic brick for ZigZag timer]

the basic idea is that instead of adding 1 to your “timer” you add an “increment” property.
You then switch this "increment" to -1 when it reaches 4 and back to 1 (effectively +1) again when the “timer” value is back to 0

to switch the "increment" property from +1 to -1 I do some fancy math (inverting the value and doubling it)

For a simpler version, you could also do it with 2 separate logic flows like here:[image]